# trouble installing eventor wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

After successfully installing the Eventor Wordpess theme and activating it I get this warning message :

> Warning: require_once(/opt/lampp/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/Eventor/inc/shortcodes/tinymce_loader.php): failed to open stream: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type in /opt/lampp/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/eventor_v1.9.1_ThenesKingdom/functions.php on line 419
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/Eventor/inc/shortcodes/tinymce_loader.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/eventor_v1.9.1_ThenesKingdom/functions.php on line 419

Comment: /opt/lampp/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/Eventor/inc/shortcodes/tinymce_loader.php  check the path carefully..

Comment: "/opt/lampp/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/Eventor/inc/shortcodes/tinymc‌​e_loader.php" this path exists. I also did check the file and the folder permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of the absolute path, use wordpress to figure it out...

```
$url= get_site_url().'/wp-content/themes/Eventor/inc/shortcodes/tinymce_loader.php';
```

this is of course assuming you have the wordpress install in htdocs folder.

Also check your apache modules for "mod_redirect" , it should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

check if you give sufficient permission to folder and files

also check your owner ship permission

also check if your theme is not corrupted

Comment: Can you think of another reason that causes this kind of problem please ?

Comment: Normaly if the theme is corrupted, the wordpress theme installation wizard will notify me but the installation procedure was completed successfully. The the problem when activating it .